# Flex Box, align last 2 items, at the bottom of flex box

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components

I have a vertical navBar on the left side of the screen, filled with some navigation items. Look a the example bellow. I want to align within the menu 2 items at the top, 2 items at the bottom. Here is my navigation:

```
<List>
  <Item>
    <Icon />
    <span class="sc-AxiKw hDoHET">Templates</span>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Icon />
    <span class="sc-AxiKw hDoHET">My Projects</span>
  </Item>
 
  <hr class="MuiDivider-root">
  <Item>
    <Icon />
    <span class="sc-AxiKw hDoHET">Profile</span>
  </Item>
  <Item>
    <Icon />
    <span class="sc-AxiKw hDoHET">Logout</span>
  </Item>
</List>
```

My CSS styles are:

```
export const List = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flext-start;
`;

export const Item = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  ${({ bottom }) => bottom && 'margin-top: auto'}
`;
```

The current implementation aligns at the bottom only the last element

Comment: It's a React component, using styled components

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all, Please categories First two item is a div and next two item in another div after that we could simple flex-box**

```
  export const List = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
;
```

*This might do it*

Comment: yes, this might help, but the thing is Item component in being mapped from and array:
`['Templates', 'My Projects', 'Profile', 'Log Out'].map(element => (<Item>{element}</Item>));`

Comment: how did you place `<hr/>` between those tags in question above?

Comment: I have a flag in the array: `{name: My Porjects, hasBottomDivider: true}`